# How to use aggregation pipeline for updating multiple documents and insert items in an array if not found by object property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very new to MongoDB and I need to do a somewhat complex Update operation on my collection.

I have this kind of collection:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4
  }
]
```

I want to update my collection so that every document ends with an `extension` array that contains an item with Key `Name` and also an item with Key `Age`.

There are 4 types of existing documents in my collection:

- A document missing the `extension` property altogether. For these, I want to create the `extension` array and insert 2 items. One with key `Name` and value "Default" and another item with key `Age` and value 99.
- A document missing an item with key `Name` in its `extension` array. I want to insert an item with key `Name` and value "Default".
- A document missing an item with key `Age` in its `extension` array. I want to insert an item with key `Age` and value 99.
- A document that already has an item with a key `Name` and an item with a key `Age` in its extension array. I don't want to update these.

I want to use aggregation pipeline to update my collection, but I am not sure what to use as the query and as the update commands to achieve that.

I think I need something like that:

```
{
    update: "MyCollection",
    updates: [
        {
            q: { xxxxxxxxxx },
            u: [ 
                    extensions: {
                        yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                    }
                ],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
}
```

In the end, my collection above would look like that after the update:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 99
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Default"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "extension": [
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Default"
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 99
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to do all your operations in one query ?

Comment: @Nur Thanks for your reply. I don't mind doing many updates, although I'd like to use the most effective method performance-wise as I have over 200k documents to update

Comment: @Nur Yes I would gladly try that :D

Comment: Its so easy, Try [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) , use [exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator, to push data use [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#mongodb-update-up.-push) update operator

Comment: @Nur well that is where I am having difficulty with the syntax and building the right queries 

Comment: I was writing your answer, and about to post, but someone  already answered,  Also I notice that it should `$ne` not  `$exists` ...

Comment: @Nur you can add your answer and I will hapilly upvote it! I will accept in the end the solution that worked for me

Comment: Thanks , But There is no different with @TusharGupta answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option -1

You can do it by running two update queries

**1) Add Age**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/S12_Efvwa7d

```
db.collection.update(
    { "extension.key": { $ne: "Age" } },
    { $push: { "extension": { "key": "Age", "value": 99 } } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

---

**2) Add Name**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nkh4WS30tvC

```
db.collection.update(
    { "extension.key": { $ne: "Name" } },
    { $push: { "extension": { "key": "Name", "value": "Default" } } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

[db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

---

### Option -2

You can combine them and make a single query using [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
    { 
        updateMany :
        {
         "filter": { "extension.key": { $ne: "Name" } },
         "update": { $push: { "extension": { "key": "Name", "value": "Default" } } }
        }
   },
   { 
        updateMany :
        {
         "filter": { "extension.key": { $ne: "Age" } },
         "update": { $push: { "extension": { "key": "Age", "value": 99 } } }
        }
   }
] )
```

Comment: This looks clean! Thank you, I will try that :) hopefully it's fast enough

Comment: That's great! I will benchmark both :) thank you very much

Comment: @ ibiza, Also remember to report your benchmark  result here!